# How to fix 'no implicit conversion of Symbol into Hash' in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm just starting to learn Ruby, and I tried making a simple script to ssh into a server. Here's the code snippet from my class:

```
require 'rubygems' if RUBY_VERSION < '1.9.0'
require 'sensu-plugin/check/cli'
gem 'net-ssh', '= 1.1.4'
require 'net/ssh'

class SshServer < Sensu::Plugin::Check::CLI

  option :host,
         short: '-h HOST',
         description: 'Server to ssh into',
         required: true

  def run
    puts "SSHing #{config[:host]} ..."
    Net::SSH.start(config[:host]) do |ssh|
      puts ssh.exec!('hostname')
      puts "Logging out..."
    end
end
```

I tried putting out the value of config[:host] and hard-coding the server name, and also config.get. No luck. I'm on Ruby version 2.0.0.

This is the full error message. Sorry couldn't put it in a code block because it was triggering the 'too much code' warning:

Check failed to run:

```
no implicit conversion of Symbol into Hash, [
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/container.rb:141:in `merge'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/container.rb:141:in `register'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/definition-context.rb:123:in `method_missing'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/net-ssh-1.1.4/lib/net/ssh/transport/ossl/hmac/services.rb:30:in `block (2 levels) in register_services'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/net-ssh-1.1.4/lib/net/ssh/transport/ossl/hmac/services.rb:29:in `each'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/net-ssh-1.1.4/lib/net/ssh/transport/ossl/hmac/services.rb:29:in `block in register_services'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/container.rb:107:in `define'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/container.rb:250:in `block in namespace_define'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/container.rb:177:in `call'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/container.rb:177:in `block in namespace'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/lifecycle/singleton.rb:42:in `call'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/lifecycle/singleton.rb:42:in `block in call'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/lifecycle/singleton.rb:40:in `synchronize'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/lifecycle/singleton.rb:40:in `call'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/service-point.rb:122:in `instance'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/container.rb:308:in `get'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/container.rb:251:in `namespace_define'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/net-ssh-1.1.4/lib/net/ssh/transport/ossl/hmac/services.rb:26:in `register_services'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/container.rb:365:in `require'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/definition-context.rb:77:in `require'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/net-ssh-1.1.4/lib/net/ssh/transport/ossl/services.rb:34:in `block in register_services'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/container.rb:107:in `define'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/container.rb:250:in `block in namespace_define'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/container.rb:177:in `call'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/container.rb:177:in `block in namespace'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/lifecycle/singleton.rb:42:in `call'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/lifecycle/singleton.rb:42:in `block in call'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/lifecycle/singleton.rb:40:in `synchronize'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/lifecycle/singleton.rb:40:in `call'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/service-point.rb:122:in `instance'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/container.rb:308:in `get'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/container.rb:251:in `namespace_define'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/net-ssh-1.1.4/lib/net/ssh/transport/ossl/services.rb:30:in `register_services'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/container.rb:365:in `require'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/definition-context.rb:77:in `require'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/net-ssh-1.1.4/lib/net/ssh/transport/services.rb:137:in `block in register_services'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/container.rb:107:in `define'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/container.rb:250:in `block in namespace_define'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/container.rb:177:in `call'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/container.rb:177:in `block in namespace'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/lifecycle/singleton.rb:42:in `call'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/lifecycle/singleton.rb:42:in `block in call'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/lifecycle/singleton.rb:40:in `synchronize'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/lifecycle/singleton.rb:40:in `call'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/service-point.rb:122:in `instance'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/container.rb:308:in `get'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/container.rb:251:in `namespace_define'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/net-ssh-1.1.4/lib/net/ssh/transport/services.rb:23:in `register_services'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/container.rb:365:in `require'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/definition-context.rb:77:in `require'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/net-ssh-1.1.4/lib/net/ssh/session.rb:126:in `block in initialize'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/container.rb:107:in `define'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/net-ssh-1.1.4/lib/net/ssh/session.rb:106:in `initialize'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/net-ssh-1.1.4/lib/net/ssh.rb:47:in `new'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/net-ssh-1.1.4/lib/net/ssh.rb:47:in `start'", "check-directory-exists.rb:59:in `run'", 
"/u/user/.gem/ruby/gems/sensu-plugin-1.4.7/lib/sensu-plugin/cli.rb:58:in `block in <class:CLI>'"
]
```

Comment: please post full code and full backtrace errors in your question or we can't figure out where your error is even being raised.

Comment: I've added the full error message.

Comment: can you try to output only the `config` and see what the result?
Also, try to pin down on which line/ where exactly, the error is occurring. the error message you posted does not elaborate much on that

Comment: I printed out config[:host] and it's the name of the server that I am trying to connect to. Putting the config prints out {host=>"server02"}

Comment: how and where is config defined?  I was able to get the same error but config is not defined so I added a line to define it in the first line of the run method.

Comment: I can print the value of config and config[:host] out so I'm guessing it is a built-in construct which works similar to using argparse in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Updated

I was able to find a compatible version with your ruby version. I tested this with ruby version

> `ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [x86_64-darwin18.2.0]`

With that version followed by:

```
gem install net-ssh --version 3.0.2
```

I was able to get my code below working without your error.

#### Original answer

The problem appears to be in the old version of `net-ssh` I tried a basic test with a working SSH server and got the same error with your version, but using the latest version `5.2.0` with no error.  I also used this format:

```
def run
  puts "SSHing #{config[:host]} ..."
  Net::SSH.start( config[:host],
                  :password=> 'password',
                  :port=> 22,
                  :username=> 'username') do |ssh|

    puts ssh.exec!('hostname')
    puts "Logging out..."
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @lacostenycoder. However it seems my version of Ruby (2.0.0) does not support net-ssh version > 1.1.4. Version 5.2.0 needs Ruby 2.2.6.

Comment: @Neosapien see updated answer. Looks like I found a working gem version for ruby 2.0.0

Comment: Brilliant! That did it! Also had to add require 'etc' to the script because it threw a "Check failed to run: uninitialized constant Net::SSH::Etc" error. Thank you.